# The Solution to Exercise 4, page 12, of Gamelin's "Introduction to Topology".

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm looking at exercise 4 in page 12 of Gamelin's *Introduction to Topology*.

The problem is stated as follows:

> Suppose that $F$ is a subset of the first category in a metric space $X$ and $E$ is a subset of $F$. Show by an example that $E$ may not be of the first category in the metric space $F$.

The solution to the exercise says that $\Bbb R$ is of the first category in $\Bbb R^2$ but not of the first category in itself.

I understand the part that $\Bbb R$ is not of the first category in itself. I think it is since every singleton subsets of $\Bbb R$ is nowhere dense but the countable union of the sets cannot be $\Bbb R$ since then $\Bbb R$ must have empty interior, which is clearly false.

However, I don't see how to prove that $\Bbb R$ is of the first category in $\Bbb R^2$. How can I show this?

Comment: It is closed and has empty interior (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$), hence is nowhere dense, hence of the first category.

Comment: Hi new user. Welcome! You might like to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Answer (score 1):

That $\mathbb{R}$ is not of the first category doesn't follow from the fact that singletons are nowhere dense but because it is a complete metric space and the result follows from Baire's category theorem.
However, when seeing $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, note that a line is closed and has empty interior so it is itself nowhere dense. Writing $\mathbb{R}$ as an union of itself makes it of the first category in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Baird's category theorem (one form of it) states that every complete metric space is a Baire space. Although the definition of Baires space states that for every countable collection of dense open subsets $(U_n)$ their intersection $\bigcap U_n$ is dense, an equivalence is that every open subset is of the second category. With this in mind, note that $\mathbb{R}$ is an open subset of itself, so it is of second category.

For your second comment, it is true that $\mathbb{R}$ is not properly a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but we are thinking of it as homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, say, the set $\{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. You can see this subset as a metric space with the metric that it inherits from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then you obtain a space that is quite similar to $\mathbb{R}$. Is something similar as saying that $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: oh that explains it. However, I don't quite get the first part of your answer that says it follows because it is a complete metric space and the result follows from Baire's theorem. Can you elaborate a bit more on how it follows?

Comment: Also, this is a trivial question but the very obvious looking fact that R is a subset of R2 is a bit confusing to me. A is a subset of B if all elements of A belong to B. But while points in R are represented with a single number like 1 points in R2 are represented as an ordered pair. So where does a real number in a real line belong in R2?

Comment: @user135204 By abuse of notation. One often identifies $\mathbb{R}$ with the subset $\{(x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and similar for the "inclusion" $\mathbb{R}^m \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ if $m < n$) thus viewing it as a subset although strictly it isn't. Keeping the notation immaculately correct at all times would make it unbearably cumbersome.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Oh so it is not the case that $\mathbb{R}$ subseteq $\mathbb{R}^2$ but {(x,0):x∈R} is? I was confused because in linear algebra we don't consider lines of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such as t(1,0) as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @user135204 With the usual constructions of $\mathbb{R}$, you don't have $\mathbb{R}^m\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ for $m\neq n$ (it _might_ be possible to have a construction in which you have such an inclusion, set theory allows weird things, but I don't see how one could do it). However, you have a "natural" embedding of the lower-dimensional spaces into the higher-dimensional ones, and for convenience, that natural embedding is often tacitly omitted and one refers to the one space as a subset of the other. I find this is not an ideal situation to use that tacit convention, but I'm not the author.